# GOLang: Nested XML to JSON

Tags: jquery, json, xml, go, output

Hello StackOverFLowers!!

I'm trying to figure out how to given XML input, to convert it to JSON using GOlang. For example...

`<version>0.1</version>
    <termsofService>http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html</termsofService>
    <features>
        <feature>conditions</feature>
    </features>`

Would be turned into

`"version": "0.1",
    "termsofService": "http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html",
    "features": { "feature": "conditions" },`

I'm getting the `version` and `termsofservice` correctly, but I can't figure out how to return nested ones like `features`. Is it something i'll have to hardcode?

CODE:

```
    type reportType struct{
    Version xml.CharData        `xml:"version"`
    TermsOfService xml.CharData `xml:"termsofService"
    `
    Features xml.CharData       `xml:"features>feature"`
    Zip      xml.CharData       `xml:"current_observation>display_location>zip"`
    Problem myErrorType     `xml:"error"`
}
type myErrorType struct{
    TypeOfError xml.CharData `xml:"type"`
    Desciption xml.CharData `xml:"description"`
}
type reportTypeJson struct{
    Version        string  `json:"version"`;
    TermsOfService string `json:"termsofService"`;
    Features    string `json:"features feature" `;
    Zip           string `json:"current_observation > display_location > zip"`;
}
func main() {
    fmt.Println("data is from WeatherUnderground.")
    fmt.Println("https://www.wunderground.com/")
    var state, city string
    str1 := "What is your state?"
    str2 := "What is your city?"
    fmt.Println(str1)
    fmt.Scanf("%s", &state)
    fmt.Println(str2)
    fmt.Scanf("%s", &city)
    baseURL := "http://api.wunderground.com/api/";
    apiKey := "YouDontNeedToKnow"
    var query string

    //set up the query
    query = baseURL+apiKey +
    "/conditions/q/"+
    url.QueryEscape(state)+ "/"+
    url.QueryEscape(city)+ ".xml"
    fmt.Println("The escaped query: "+query)

    response, err := http.Get(query)
    doErr(err, "After the GET")
    var body []byte
    body, err = ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    doErr(err, "After Readall")
    fmt.Println(body);
    fmt.Printf("The body: %s\n",body)

    //Unmarshalling
    var report reportType
    xml.Unmarshal(body, &report)
    fmt.Printf("The Report: %s\n", report)
    fmt.Printf("The description is [%s]\n",report.Problem.Desciption)

    //Now marshal the data out in JSON
    var data []byte
    var output reportTypeJson
    output.Version = string(report.Version);
    output.TermsOfService = string(report.TermsOfService)

    output.Features= string(report.Features)
    output.Zip=string(report.Zip)
    data,err = json.MarshalIndent(output,"","      ")
    doErr(err, "From marshalIndent")
    fmt.Printf("JSON output nicely formatted: \n%s\n",data)


}
func doErr( err error, message string){
    if err != nil{
        log.Panicf("ERROR: %s %s \n", message, err.Error())
    }


}
```

OUTPUT:

`JSON output nicely formatted: 
{
      "version": "0.1",
      "termsofService": "http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html",
      "features \u003e feature": "conditions",
      "current_observation \u003e display_location \u003e zip": "64068"
}`

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not getting the desired output because the definition of your json struct is incorrect. You have;

```
type reportTypeJson struct{
    Version        string  `json:"version"`;
    TermsOfService string `json:"termsofService"`;
    Features    string `json:"features feature" `;
    Zip           string `json:"current_observation > display_location > zip"`;
}
```

Which denotes features as a string but it's actually an object, either a `map[string]string` or it's own struct which would be defined as such;

```
type Features struct {
     Feature string `json:"feature"`
}
```

Given the fields name is plural, I would guess it's intended to be a collection so changing your struct to

```
type reportTypeJson struct{
    Version        string  `json:"version"`;
    TermsOfService string `json:"termsofService"`;
    Features    map[string]string `json:"features"`;
    Zip           string `json:"current_observation > display_location > zip"`;
}
```

is probably what you're looking for. Of course, this means you'll have to modify some other code which assigns values from the xml struct to the json one or whatever but I think you can figure that out fine on your own :D

EDIT: The section below is where you convert your xml type into a json type (ie allocate an instance of the reportTypeJson and assign values from the reportType to it so that you can call the json marshal on it to produce the output). Assuming you're using the definition of `reportTypeJson` from above which has `Features` as a `map[string]string` you just have to modify the one line where you set `output.Features`. In the sample below I do this inline with 'composite literal' syntax. This allows you to instantiate/allocate the collection while assigning values to it at the same time.

```
//Now marshal the data out in JSON
var data []byte
var output reportTypeJson
output.Version = string(report.Version);
output.TermsOfService = string(report.TermsOfService)

output.Features= map[string]string{"features":string(report.Features)} // allocate a map, add the 'features' value to it and assign it to output.Features
output.Zip=string(report.Zip)
data,err = json.MarshalIndent(output,"","      ")
doErr(err, "From marshalIndent")
fmt.Printf("JSON output nicely formatted: \n%s\n",data)
```

Comment: Mr. Mcdonnal, before I lose your attention, could you give me an example of how I would go about modifying the code to be able to accept what you have suggested? I have a final tomorrow and I'm still trying to fully grasp the concept

Comment: @BeccaBohem yeah for sure, I had to go to a meeting before I could inspect that part of the code. I'll edit right now with that part as well.

Comment: Thank you so much, my final grade thanks you as well!